# Is it lossless to cut WAV files into segments and join them again?

Tags: processing, cutting

I asked about [a Non-Linear Editor for sound that works from plain-text files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/75487/audio-production-with-a-non-linear-editor-that-works-from-plain-text-files). As it does not seem to exist, I programmed one with FFMPEG. The text input is:

```
## take_1.wav

-ss 3.32179
-to 7.57171
any notes on this

## take_1.wav

-ss 11.82790
-to 15.22180
some more notes

## take_2.wav

-ss 15.76000
-to 20.20920
more notes
```

and I extract those segments with FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i take2.wav -ss 15.76000 -to 20.20920 -ac 1 temp3.wav
```

and then join them with Python's `wave` module, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python):

```
def join_audio(infiles, outfile):
    data = []
    for infile in infiles:
        w = wave.open(infile, 'rb')
        data.append( [w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())] )
        w.close()

    output = wave.open(outfile, 'wb')
    output.setparams(data[0][0])
    for i in range(len(data)):
        output.writeframes(data[i][1])
    output.close()
```

I notice some discrepancies at the joins between the segments. Since WAV is uncompressed, I assume that this slicing and joining is lossless. Is that correct or am I losing some information in the process?

Comment: Wav editing should always be lossless, but cutting at non-zero points is always going to click. How are you ensuring your edit points are going to be silent? Why do you need to do this programatically rather than audio-visually? I'm sure something like Audacity would be a simple-enough tool for this job.

Comment: I was doing it programmatically to avoid the destructive editing of Audacity. Thanks for the tip on non-zero points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be lossless. You can avoid the popping sounds by doing very short fade ins/outs